# Exporting SoilGrids WCS layer as GeoTIFF in QGIS - inconsistent cell values including min/max

Tags: qgis, soilgrids

I am using QGIS (v3.30.3) to access global raster data from SoilGrids (v2-0) via the "Add WCS Layer" functionality. I want to export these layers as a GeoTiff so they are available from the hard drive. However, the exported layers do not match the original layers in terms of the pixel values - the max value is always higher in the new exported layers than in the WCS versions.

Using the cec_5-15cm_mean raster as an example, I load this into QGIS using Add WCS Layer. When loading, I am given 2 options for the CRS, EPSG:4326 or EPSG:3857, I choose the former. The format is GEOTIFF_INT16 / GTiff.

Then I export this as a GeoTIFF using "Save Raster Layer as". I keep suggested settings for everything (though tried different extents to speed up process). The CRS is EPSG:4326, though  World_Goode_Homolosine_Land is also offered.

I then end up with an output that, according to Symbology, has a different max value (max is >15% higher than original), and some cells that have very different values, sometimes differing by as much as 30%.

Why could this be and is there a workaround?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @JoeL5475, welcome to GIS.StackExchange. The CRSs you refer impose massive distortions, since the original maps were produced on an equal area projection. However, the differences you refer are excessive in this regard. Please verify whether these inconsistent values are also present with the Homolosine Land projection.